# Problem With errorPlacement in jQuery Validator

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a question about the errorPlacement Method in jQuery Validator Plug-in:
I want to put an Error Message in a div.

Before i continue... Yeah, the code is horrible, i'm working in a project that isn't mine, without documentation or anything that i help me. But i cannot write from zero all the webpage.

Ok, let's continue, this is a little section of the HTML code:

```
<tr>
  <th height="24" scope="col">
    <div align="left" class="Style69 Style72 Style75">
      <span class="Style77">Name</span>
    </div>
  </th>
  <th height="24" colspan="3" scope="col">
    <div align="left">
      <span class="Style69 Style72 Style75">
        <input id="txtname" name="txtname" class="required"
        type="text" size="30" />
      </span>
    </div>
  </th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td height="17" colspan="4">
    <div id="errorMessage"></div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The Layout is a table, and, inside of this table are placed all the elements (inputboxes and select's).

My question is, how can i place the error message in the div "errorMessage"?

I'm doing something like this:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
   error.appendTo(element.prev().next().next());
 }
```

But it doesn't work. Then, I've Tried This:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
   error.appendTo(element.prev().next().next().find("#errorMessage"));
 }
```

And nothing happens.
The "Div" and "Span" tags are part of the DOM?

Any Suggestion?

Comment: Does your page contains "errorMessage" div more than once? If your answer is no, maybe just $("#errorMessage").html(error); is enough.

Comment: Yes to what anilca said! Element IDs must be unique, so there can only be one element with ID `errorMessage` on your page. So, all you need to do to select that element is `$('#errorMessage')`.

Comment: @Matt Ball Thank you So much! To you and anilca. Really It Worked! And yes, i know, all the Div ID's in the webpage are unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) gives no results, there's no previous sibling to your `<input>` here:

```
  <span class="Style69 Style72 Style75">
    <input id="txtname" name="txtname" class="required"
    type="text" size="30" />
  </span>
```

Something like this should work:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
  element.closest('tr').next().find('.errorMessage').append(error);
}
```

This uses [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to go up to the `<tr>`, gets the [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) sibling (the next `<tr>`) then [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the `class="errorMessage"` element inside.

With this, change your `id` to a class, like this:

```
<div class="errorMessage"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, It Worked Too! Thank you So Much! Your Solution and The anilca's solution worked perfectly. And, My Apologies for this question, I'm really a Begginer. Thank you Guys!

Comment: @Astantler - it's a *perfectly* valid question, and welcome :)